# Turn recursion to fold?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

I wrote this code that loops through the lines of a file handle and does an arbitrary action with it. I don't think it should need to be recursive - can I make it into a fold action?

Thanks!

```
processHandle :: Handle -> (String->IO ()) -> IO ()
processHandle h fn = do
                   eof <- hIsEOF h
                   if eof then
                     return ()
                    else do
                      myLine <- hGetLine h
                      fn myLine
                      processHandle h fn
```

Comment: I think you've just written the fold-like action you seek! There is no actual fold, per se, because you don't have an actual container full of values but rather a handle that lets you use I/O to get values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manually working with handles is very eschewed in Haskell. It doesn't play well together with a functional programming style.

For a simple input processor like this, it's probably the best to just read *the entire file* as one (lazy) string, and process the lines of that:

```
processHandle h fn = mapM_ fn . lines =<< hgetContents h
```

Of course this can also be written as a fold, just look up [the definition of `mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#mapM_).

Now, this lazy-IO approach doesn't work as well for many serious applications. If this isn't one huge file, then you may be good if you just read the file strictly [with the `Data.Text` equivalent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:readFile). Else, if you really need to read lines interleaved with the processing steps, better look into [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit).

Comment: Oh clever. Thanks.